# How can I change the color of text in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I would like to select a range of text in a MS Word document and change it from the default black to a different color.

How can I do that?

(I'm using Word for Mac version 15.26. It was installed through an Office 365 subscription, so I think it's the latest version.)

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff -- Just select the text you want to change, and then change it via the Font Color option.  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the steps below:
Step 1: Select the text you want to change color.

[image]

Step 2: click on the 'Home' menu bar, find A with Red underline in Font section and click on drop-down arrow and simply select the color you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an option if you select and hover over the word, or on the top toolbar that has an A with a coloured line underneath it.  That is where the colour setting is found.